# How do I convert an array on the client into a byte[] on the server?

Tags: c#, string, encoding, arrays

I have a `class` that `encrypts` and `decrypts` a string. It uses `rijndael`. Anyways, I am trying to store an encrypted value on the client. That works all fine and dandy. My problem is when I want to decrypt the value, I need the `Key and IV(InitVector)` that was used to encrypt the string. They are `byte[]` values. I currently output those to the client through a `javascript` variable. I need them when I call a service, as this app talks to a mainframe and it needs the users credentials. They output to the client in the form of

`var vector = [143,147,31,70,195,72,228,190,152,222,65,240,152,183,0,161];`

I am able to pass that value to my `service` as a string. My question is , inside my service, how can I convert this `string` back into a `byte array`? I have tried

`Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("[143,147,31,70,195,72,228,190,152,222,65,240,152,183,0,161]");`

But that is not what I want. That tries to make a new `Byte[]` from that string value. I need a byte array who's values are that inside the string. Is this possible? Please provide a quick sample if you know how to do this.

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encode the bytes in base64, using [System.Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) and FromBase64String.

**Edit**: this program demonstrates this in more detail

```
class A{
      public static void Main()
      {
       byte[] a = new byte[]{143,147,31,70,195,72,228,190,152,222,65,240,152,183,0,161};
       string s = System.Convert.ToBase64String(a);
       System.Console.WriteLine(s);
       byte[] b = System.Convert.FromBase64String(s);
       System.Console.Write("[");
       foreach (var n in b)
           System.Console.Write(n+",");
       System.Console.WriteLine("]");
      }
}
```

Comment: this works great Martin. Now tho when I decrypt, it tacks on null bytes. I just do a .replace("\0", string.Empty) and it seems to be ok. Is there a more elegant way? Thanks All!!!

Comment: I can't see where you get a null byte from (I also don't understand what you mean by "decrypt" - there is no operation called "decrypt" here anywhere I can see). See my edit; in this program, the result is exactly the same as the input.

Answer (score 1):

I think these two methods in C# might help you.  I have used these with my crypto routine in order to get a byte[] for my IV and Key.  Is it possible that you can output a string returned from the GetString method below in Javascript and then use that value to call the service with?

```
private static byte[] GetArray(string input)
    {
        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string hex = input.Substring(i, 2);
            bytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToUInt32(hex, 16)));
        }

        return bytes.ToArray();
    }

    private static string GetString(byte[] input)
    {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
        foreach (byte b in input)
        {
            buffer.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
        }
        return buffer.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I was in the process of posting something basically the same. +1